# How to parse html and create array from dt/dd

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have a select element for which I want to dynamically create the option values using information from another website.  The information can be seen at http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Classes.  It is the list of 'Base Classes'.  I have tried using the DOMDocument class, but I can't see any way of using a url instead of an html file.  I have tried using file_get_html and a foreach loop, but can't make it work with the format of the data on the website.  It is in a dt/dd element, and the elements don't have id's.  What would be the best way to pull the information off the website, and create an option value for each class in my select element?

Comment: Use XPath. I just tested this JavaScript code in Firebug and it returns an array of the text of the base classes: `$x('//big[text()="Base Classes"]/../..//a/text()').map(function(node) { return node.textContent; })`. You should be able to use the same XPath expression in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/ to test the query. You would end up with something like this.

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Classes';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();

//from file
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

//Creating a new DOMPath
$Xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//  Get links
//  //big Selects all <big> elements in the document.
//  [text()="Base Classes"] with text "base classes"
//  /.. get parent class
//  /.. get parent class
//  //a select all <a> elements
//  /text() get text
$query = '//big[text()="Base Classes"]/../..//a/text()';

$entries = $Xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {

    echo $entry->nodeValue . "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  I have been trying to reverse engineer your snippet, and I think I have everything figured out except for the '/../..'.  Based on what I've read, and your comments, /.. gets the parent of the current node.  If the '//big...' portion of the query selects all <big> elements with the text 'Base Classes', why do we want the parent node?  Furthermore, why do we want the parent of that parent node?  Or do I have it backwards?  Does the '/..' work right to left, such that we begin with '/a' and get the parent of that node (<dd>), and the parent of that node (<dl>)?

Comment: Also, the code is not working and I think it is because it doesn't recognize the DOMDocument class.  In the index.php file the variables '$dom' are higlighted, and the hint is suggesting to create the DOMDocument class.  I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 with XAMPP, and PHP 5.5.24.  In the phpinfo() section, Libxml is active and enabled, and DOM/XML is enabled.  In the php.ini file I have extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext".  I have seen forums talking about a php-xml module, and a dom extension, but I don't know how to implement that.